# How to check if integer variable is a whole number or not

Tags: python

Possibly important: I am running python on a TI 84 Plus CE calculator.

I'm trying to write a program that checks if a imputed value, divided by every number up to it, is a whole number, and if so to display it.

I'm relatively new to programming, and this is my first question on stack overflow, sorry if anything is formatted wrong

here's the code so far:

```
from math import *

d=int(input("discriminant: "))
c=1
while(c<d):
  q=(d/c)
  if(q.is_integer()):
    print(q)
```

whenever I run the program, is displays

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'is_integer'

I don't understand how to fix this.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: In standard Python, the `float` type has this method since version 2.6 (extremely out of date). If you are really seeing that message than it is indeed something specific to whatever modified or ancient version you have that can run on a calculator. However, for your specific case, the underlying problem is not actually to figure out whether an arbitrary value is an integer, but whether the *division results in* an integer. Please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: Actually, it cannot be an old version of Python, only a problem specific to the calculator build. This is because, in Python 2, the `/` operator would perform C-style "integer division", so the error message would say `'int' object` instead of `'float' object`. Curiously, in Python 3.12, an `is_integer` method has been added to the `int` type, exactly so that you can write a function that accepts either an `int` or a `float` and easily check whether the input is an exact integer.

Comment: I believe you'll find your calculator isn't running Python, but [MicroPython](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/) (aka μPy)... Python for embedded systems. It's a much stripped down version of the language.